# Deleting row creating a ref issue in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a helper column with the following code

`=IF(A1<>A2,1-SUM(B1),SUM(B1))`

The table looks like

[image: Table]

When I delete a row, say row 21 in this example, I end up with a ref issue in cell B21 -

`=IF(#REF!<>A21,1-SUM(#REF!),SUM(#REF!))`

Is there any way to resolve this, perhaps with a way to sequence the formula in cell B2 such that it automatically runs the calculation and corrects based on rows being removed?

Comment: I have done the same thing as you. I also get error messages, but less: my last formula looks like this: `=IF(A20<>#REF!,1-SUM(B20),SUM(B20))`. In top of this, my values seem to be slightly different. A last remark: why are you basing your first formula on A1 and B1 when you use the first row for heading purposes. Wouldn't it be better to work, starting from A2 and B2?

Comment: Oh, now I see: the formula you mention is the one in B22, my formula is the one from B21. (In both cases after the removal, of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `offset` function to avoid this and always make the formula look to the above cell like this:

```
=IF(OFFSET(A2,-1,0)<>A2,1-SUM(OFFSET(B2,-1,0)),SUM(OFFSET(B2,-1,0)))
```

This tells to use A2 but 1 row less, making it A1. (And same for B2.)

Comment: As this does the trick, `OFFSET` being a volatile function would recalculate each cell where this formula is used at any change anywhere in the workbook, slowing the file down if you drag this down to thousands of cells. `INDEX` would only recalculate if the referenced cells are changed.

Answer (score 1):

In B2 use: `=IF(INDEX(A:A,ROW()-1)<>INDEX(A:A,ROW()),1-SUM(INDEX(B:B,ROW()-1)),SUM(INDEX(B:B,ROW()-1)))`

By using `INDEX` you can avoid referencing cells that may be deleted, which is causing the issue you have.

Comment: Hey P.b, when I paste this in to B2 I get a circular reference, any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Changed the answer to reflect cell `B2`